# Required parameters is missing while posting data from Android

Tags: php, android, post, retrofit

I have created an API which will accept multiple parameters. When I post data from Postman it works fine, but when I post from Android code it shows "require parameters missing" which I am returning from PHP if parameters mismatched.

All other APIs are working from Android but I don't know what issue I am getting here.

Here is my PHP API:

```
if (isset($_POST['tbl_gate_id']) && isset($_POST['tbl_society_id']) && isset($_POST['tbl_building_id']) && isset($_POST['reason']) && isset( $_POST[ 'vehicle_type' ]) && isset($_POST['vehicle_number']) && isset($_POST['tbl_guest_id']) && isset($_POST['tbl_watchmen_id']) && isset($_POST['tbl_flat_id'])) {
// doing my operations
} else {
    $response["status"] = 3;
    $response["message"] = "Required parameters (email or password) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Here is my Android code:

NetworkService.java

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(Constants.CREATE_GUEST_REQUEST)
Call<GuestEntryResponse> executeGuestEntryRequest(@Field("tbl_gate_id") int gateId,
                                                  @Field("tbl_society_id") int societyId,
                                                  @Field("tbl_building_id") int buildingId,
                                                  @Field("reason") String reason,
                                                  @Field("vehicle_type") String vehicleType,
                                                  @Field("vehicle_number") String vehicleNumber,
                                                  @Field("tbl_guest_id") int guestId,
                                                  @Field("tbl_watchmen_id") int watchmenId,
                                                  @Field("tbl_flat_id") int flatId);
```

MyActivityFunction.java

```
private void executeGuestEntry() {
    ConnectivityUtils objConnectivityUtils = new ConnectivityUtils();
    if(objConnectivityUtils.isNetworkAvailable(this)){
        try {
            NetworkService networkService = App.getClient(EXTENDED_URL).create(NetworkService.class);

            Call<GuestEntryResponse> call = networkService.executeGuestEntryRequest(gateId,
                    societyId,
                    buildingId,
                    reason,
                    vehicleType,
                    vehicleNumber,
                    guestId,
                    watchmenId,
                    flatId);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<GuestEntryResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GuestEntryResponse> call, Response<GuestEntryResponse> response) {

                    GuestEntryResponse guestEntryResponse = response.body();
                    Log.d("RequestActivity", "Guest : "+response.body());
                    if(guestEntryResponse != null){
                            Toast.makeText(RequestActivity.this, guestEntryResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(RequestActivity.this, "Error occur", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GuestEntryResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(RequestActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(RequestActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.network_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

How can I find the root cause?

Comment: Can you check if any of field null or something

Comment: Change API and try sending 1 or 2 parameters at first and check the same with all variables. It would point you to correct missing parameters.

Comment: I debug in android and no field is null.

Comment: @Tauqir yeah i will check one by one but one thing i am not getting same are working from postman

Comment: API and java codes seems to be correct. It is really strange why it is not working.

Comment: What content-type is android specifying and is there need to url encode your string parameters.

Comment: @Tauqir you are right. I just check one by one and got issue at vehicle_number. Now need to find out why? is there because of spaces?

Comment: Is data type is same for both side for vehicle_number?